# Embedded shell script with RCP app

Tags: eclipse, bash, shell, scripting, rcp

I have an RCP application packaged by a PDE build.
Also in this application in one of the plugins I have a directory called "scripts" with shell scripts that I want to run.
Everything works ok if I run the app from eclipse.

The weird thing is that when running PDE build the scripts directory ends up in the plugin jar. As a consequence when starting the application(outside eclipse) it cannot run the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of a lack of solution to this I have completely removed the scripts directory and replaced the functionality with a workaround: I only run single commands with System.exec(..)